# When adding the media query, the nav bar does not display

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hope someone can help me here.
I initially design the web page for a desk top.
now I am trying to gracefully - degrade, and add features for smaller screens.

What happens now, is that the navbar does not show up at all.
the header is a flex container that has 2 nested flex containers within it. 
The one on the right is supposed to display, unless the screen goes below 376px.

I am not sure why...

```css
.nav-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #0092FF;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  top: 0px;
}

header nav .logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 6.25em;
  margin-top: 22px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 40px;
}

header nav .menu .menu-item {
  display: none;
  /* position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
 */
}

@media screen and (min-width:23.5em) {
  header nav .menu {
    display: inline-block;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 6.25em;
    margin-top: 0;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  header nav .menu .menu-item .nav-link {
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-right: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 31px;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    font: Semibold 18px/22px Proxima Nova;
    align-items: center;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
  }
  header nav .menu-item .login {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 104px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin-top: 22px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header class="nav-container">
    <nav>
      <div class="logo"><img src="./images/overpass.svg" alt="overpass"></div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><button type="button" class="login">Login</button></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: You are hiding "header nav .menu .menu-item" but not displaying them when size is larger then 376. just add "header nav .menu .menu-item {display:inline-block} to your @media block.

Comment: hi Derek, I did as you suggested, but it had absolutely no effect!!

Comment: I am modifying the code to reflect the change

Comment: You have a host of syntax errors. I suggest viewing your page on a browser Inspector and fixing your various errors, first.

Comment: I have corrected the syntax errors.

Comment: still, the navbar does not display...

Comment: Is there a particular reason you removed the Stack Snippet? It was meant to make the code runnable here on Stack Overflow so that others could run it and see the problem without having to copy your code elsewhere just to see the problem...

Comment: sorry about it...

Comment: did not realize that I have moved it...

Comment: in any event, I have modified the code above to reflect the Stack Snippet. Yet, it still does not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show up the navbar, you need to add this in your media query :

```css
header nav .menu .menu-item {
  display: block;
}
```

For more explanation :

- `header nav .menu .menu-item .nav-link` = each element with *nav-link* class in header > nav > .menu > .menu-item
- `header nav .menu-item .login` = each element with *login* class in header > nav > .menu-item
- `header nav .menu .menu-item` = each element with *menu-item* class in header > nav > .menu
- So, if you set `display: none;` for `.menu-item` then you have to set `display: block;` (or other) **for the same item**, not *nav-link* or *login* class

Answer (score 0):

I have applied the suggestion from above. it works now:

```
.nav-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #0092FF;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  top: 0px;
}

header nav .logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 6.25em;
  margin-top: 22px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 40px;
}
header nav .menu .menu-item {
  display: none;
  /* position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
 */
}

@media screen and (min-width:23.5em) {
    header nav .menu {
      display: inline-block;
      display: flex;
      margin-right: 6.25em;
      margin-top: 0;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    header nav .menu .menu-item {
      display: inline-block;
      flex-direction: row;
      margin-top: 1.94em;
    }

      header nav .menu .menu-item .nav-link{
      padding-right: 60px;
      font-size:  1.125em;
      font: Semibold 18px/22px Proxima Nova;
      align-items: center;
      letter-spacing: 0;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      opacity: 1;
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: none;
    }

    header nav  .menu-item .login {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 104px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: Transparent;
      color: white;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      outline: none;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size:  1.125em;
      margin-top: -0.5em;
    }

  }
```